# Stored Procedure not returning data based on IF condition

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements

I have a stored procedure in which I am checking if a table returns any rows. If no rows are returned then just return an empty/dummy result set. If rows are returned then return the same result set.

Here's the procedure

```
BEGIN

Declare @HAS_ROWS int
SELECT @HAS_ROWS(SELECT COUNT(*) AS HAS_ROWS FROM Table1)

    If(@HAS_ROWS <= 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 NULL FROM Table1
            Return
        END
    Else
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM Table1
            Return
        END
END
```

Upon running this procedure I get the following result

```
(No column name)
0

HAS_ROWS
NULL

Title
This is title of row1
This is title of row2
```

As you can see it is returning 3 result sets and I expect it to return on only based on IF condition. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `SELECT @HAS_ROWS = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Table1;`

Comment: (Right now `SELECT @HAS_ROWS` and `(SELECT COUNT(*)...` are two separate queries.)

Comment: Also, this seems quite wasteful. Why not just code the application to deal with an empty resultset instead of a dummy one?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am using SSRS to generate report so I need this in one case (requested by customer) that if there is no record, show a blank line/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aaron is right with the @Has_Rows - it needs to be assigned with *SELECT @HAS_ROWS = ...* or *SET @HAS_ROWS = ...* (the latter has more restrictions on use).

Here is a fixed / simplified version that should work for you:

```
BEGIN
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1) = 0)
        SELECT NULL
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Table1

    RETURN
END
```